# aws amplify push says "difference between the request time and current time is too large"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify-cli

AWS *amplify push* "uploading files.." runs about 30 minutes than says
"difference between the request time and current time is too large"

There are many similar topic, but the difference are:

1. I'm on windows
2. I have different timezone: +2 hours than S3..
3. Im using aws "amplify push"

And it works for a year, without any problem.

**Update 1:**
In windows time settings I changed "internet time" to "0.amazon.pool.ntp.org" and time sync is done. (win restart done too).

**Update 2:**
amplify cli log says:

A huge amount of file push was successful, then get some error (time difference), then another thousands successful push again..

**Update 3:**
Problem resolved? I did an "amplify pull" and my modifications lost/overwritted. Then "amplify push", and its done without any errors.

**Update 4:**

When i run an "amplify pull", the amplify push worked again.
But when i modify schema.graphql (add a @key) and run "amplify push" to push the changes to AWS, the error comes back again.

:(

Comment: This error is usually thrown when your pc time is incorrect. I know you said that you've synced, but are you 100% sure? Everyone else with similar problems always had an unsynced clock. Restarting your windows should not be necessary. Timezone should not matter either, since S3 can handle this.

Comment: Yes, the time is synced. The wierd thing is:

I see 70.000 upload successful like this:
2021-08-03T09:39:34.008Z|info : amplify-provider-awscloudformation.aws-s3.uploadFile.s3.putObject

then get the first error:

2021-08-03T09:54:16.163Z|error : amplify-provider-awscloudformation.aws-s3.uploadFile.s3(
RequestTimeTooSkewed: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.

And the other 70k line is shuffled: some success, and some error..